# ScreenManager цвет текста

Tags: python, kivy

у меня есть код, где есть вкладки, мне надо сделать так, что бы 1) вкладка подсвечивалась когда пользователь находился на ней. 2) при переходе на другую вкладку цвет старой менялся на прежний,а новая изменяла цвет. Я постарался сделать это, но у меня ничего не получилось. Кто сталкивался с каким и может помочь буду очень благодарен))

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


KV = '''


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            ScrollView:

                MDList:

                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Домашнияя работа"
                        on_press:
                            root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            root.screen_manager.current = "screen 1"



                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Посещаемость"
                        on_press:
                            root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Успеваемость"
                        on_press:
                            root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                            root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"

Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "screen 1"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        id: toolbar
                        title: "Домашнияя работа"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]



            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        id: toolbar
                        title: "Домашнияя работа"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        id: toolbar
                        title: "Домашнияя работа"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''



class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)



class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальной документации есть готовый пример - https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigation-drawer/index.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я пробовал это ввести в свой код но всё без успешно.Но все равно спасибо